# RMarkdown: Generate pdf document using rmarkdown:render-function in Rcpp

Tags: r, pdf, render, r-markdown

I want to generate pdf document from my .rmd file with the rmarkdown:render-function. It works when I execute the render-function from RStudio and also RGui after setting some environment variables:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv('PATH'), 'C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64', sep=.Platform$path.sep))

Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC='C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc')
```

I also use R integration in C++ with the Rcpp package, so I can execute R Code out of C++. For some reason the render-function doesn't work when I call it via Rcpp. Maybe it has to do with the environvent variables? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take care of the `PATH` *before* you start R to affect processes started by it.

Also, it's Rcpp (with lowercase c, p and p) and it "works for me" when all tools are in the `PATH`.

Comment: ok, can you tell which relevant tools you have in your PATH environment variable? thanks!

Comment: I get the following error:
Error in grDevices::pdf(NULL, width, height, ...) : 
In addition: Warning message: 
failed to load encoding file 'WinAnsi.enc'